# What is the meaning of Rose's cameo in the Midnight episode?

Tags: doctor-who, cameo

In the [tenth episode of the fourth series ("*Midnight*")](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Midnight_%28TV_story%29), after the shuttle is shaken, we see a very brief cameo of Rose Tyler on a screen (about 16:30 into the episode). Although the feed appears to be mute, you can see her saying "Doctor" twice. The Doctor doesn't notice her, nor does anybody else.

[image]

It could be a warning to the dangerous situation ahead but it could also be a warning to the upcoming arc. Is there more information about the meaning of this?

Comment: Have you seen through to *Stolen Earth* yet (the season finale for that season?) If not, then the answer is a huge spoiler.

Comment: @MichaelEdenfield: Yes, I'm at Season 7 now. Maybe I forgot some details of past episode :)

Comment: Does anyone else notice it also seems like she isn't shouting "Doctor!Doctor!",but "Doctor!Help me!" or "us!"?

Comment: @Kaimonster101 it's actually a clip from the episode where Rose's face got stolen by the TV monster, so it's likely she is saying "Help me!".

Answer (score 21, accepted):

That was Rose trying to warn the Doctor of the coming events in *The Stolen Earth* & *Journey's End*.  If you watch the footage, she is trying to get the Doctor's attention as she is obviously yelling "Doctor! Doctor!".  She also cameoed in *[Partners in Crime](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Partners_in_Crime)* where she appears to just be keeping an eye on the Doctor:

> Donna then calls her mum to say she's put the car keys in a certain bin for her to collect before asking a blonde girl to tell her mother, "that bin there"; the girl is Rose Tyler. As Donna returns to the TARDIS, Rose walks off down the street and disappears into thin air.

But we also see a similar screen appearance (the same as in *Midnight*), but in the TARDIS, during *The Poison Sky*.  Rose's reappearances are a consistent motif through Season 4, so I'd concluded that they obviously lead up to

> her reappearance and the events of the final two episodes.

Comment: One correction - having watched it recently, it was instantly clear to me she was looking for the Doctor even in the Partners in Crime appearance. It was likely the presence of alien activity that had attracted her to the scene, correctly suspecting that it would lead her to the Doctor, but she misses him by moments, as alluded to by the deliberate cinematography/framing of those scenes, as well as the dejected, slightly wistful expression she wears when looking on at the scene that, unbeknownst to her, he'd just left.